# How to update map from method in Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I am busy creating a UI where a user can input a set of waypoints, an origin and a destination and a computed route is output. To do this I am making use of the Google Maps API.
I am doing this with Vue.js. I currently have two methods which are executed. The first `initMap()` is executed when the Vue.js component is mounted, the second method `directions()` is executed when a button is pressed on the UI (I left it out to make the code shorter).

**The problem:**
Currently both the `initMap()` & `directions()` methods are creating a new instantiation of `google.maps.Map` every time it is run. This creates two calls to the Google Maps API. How can I set the  `directions()`  method to update the existing map instead of having to create a new call each time?

```
<template>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height:100%;"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { loadedGoogleMapsAPI } from "./GoogleMapsApiLoader";

export default {
  mounted() {
    loadedGoogleMapsAPI.then(() => {
      this.initMap();
    });
  },

  data() {
    return {
      mapOptions: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {

    initMap() {
    //This function initialises the page with a new google map element
      mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: -28.4792625, lng: 24.6727135 },
        mapTypeId: "terrain"
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    },

directions() {
    //This directions method is executed once a button is pressed on the UI
    //How do I get this directions method to update the map already created in 
    //initMap() instead of creating a second map and generating a second call
    //to the Google Maps API?
      mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: -28.4792625, lng: 24.6727135 },
        mapTypeId: "terrain"
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

      directionsService.route(
        {
          origin: "Kimberley, Northern-Cape, South Africa",
          destination: "Potchefstroom, South Africa",
          travelMode: "DRIVING"
        },

        function(response, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              //I plan to do some post-processing here
          } 
          else {
            window.alert("Directions request failed: " + status);
          }
        }
      );

      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You are creating new map instance each time `directions()` is called.

```
 mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: -28.4792625, lng: 24.6727135 },
        mapTypeId: "terrain"
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); //--> here


      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      ... // rest of the code
```

### Solution

save the `map` instance in one of the `data` variables in component and use the same in `directions()` method.

```
data() {
    return {
      mapOptions: {},
      map: null // --> HERE
    };
  },
  methods: {

    initMap() {
    //This function initialises the page with a new google map element
      mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: -28.4792625, lng: 24.6727135 },
        mapTypeId: "terrain"
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); // --> HERE
    },
directions() {
    //This directions method is executed once a button is pressed on the UI
    //How do I get this directions method to update the map already created in 
    //initMap() instead of creating a second map and generating a second call
    //to the Google Maps API?
      mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: -28.4792625, lng: 24.6727135 },
        mapTypeId: "terrain"
      };
      //var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); //--> HERE delete this


      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

      directionsService.route(
        {
          origin: "Kimberley, Northern-Cape, South Africa",
          destination: "Potchefstroom, South Africa",
          travelMode: "DRIVING"
        },

        function(response, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              //I plan to do some post-processing here
          } 
          else {
            window.alert("Directions request failed: " + status);
          }
        }
      );

      directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map); // --> HERE
    }
```

Comment: If I wanted to change the `mapOptions` of the map in the `directions()` method, how would I update the map instance?

Comment: you can do it via map class.[reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).eg `this.map.setZoom(zoom)`.Similarily there are functions for others.

Comment: How would I remove the previous directions from the map if I update it? `directionsDisplay.setMap(null)` does not work as each new method iteration creates a new instance of the `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();` . I tried moving the `var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();` to global however this does not work.

Comment: you can refactor the code the same way `map` variable has been moved outside into one of the data variables so that `data` includes `directionService` and `directionDisplay`. You can initialise these variables in `initMap()` and then call `this.directionsDisplay.setMap(null)` inside `directions`